# Oracle, GlassFish Tools in Eclipse Enterprise

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, server

Trying to setup eclipse following Definitive Guide to JSF in Java EE 8.  Choosing 'No servers are available' does not list the required 'Oracle, GlassFish Tools'.  I am using Eclipse version: 2021-06, on Windows 10 64-bit, Java JDK 15.0.2.  I've trying installing GlassFish Tools from the eclipse market place without success.  For some reason, on the Define New Server page, Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost in listed as the Server name, Apache tomcat v9.0 is listed as the Server runtime environment.

Should I be re-installing eclipse for the enterprise?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Payara Tools instead. I forked that initially from GlassFish Tools and added many improvements to it. It supports GlassFish as well.

The original GlassFish Tools hasn't been updated for a long time and is probably not compatible with the more recent Eclipse releases.